# ThinkPad T450s: Why only cool one of two dies?

Tags: laptop, cooling

I recently took apart my laptop to replace its SSD, and also ended up replacing the heat sink compound because of elevated temperatures (and thus fan speed and noise).

But it is obvious that there are two dies under the heat sink, which has a pad large enough to cover both of dies. However, one of them is explicitly *not* in contact with it: it sits in the space between the copper pad and the (aluminium?) frame with the screws, underneath the heat pipe.

What might be the reason for this design?[image]

Comment: Does your laptop have dedicated graphics?

Comment: The ThinkPad model number (20BX000TMD) suggests the graphics are driven by an _Intel HD Graphics 5500_ which I found described as _an **integrated** Broadwell graphics card revealed in Q1 2015_.